# how do I fix a ceiling fan light that won't light, but the fan works?

Tags: ceiling, light-fixture

the fan works, but the light won't work even though all contact tested positive for AC current I tested two ways,a 250V voltage tester that I used to test all 4 wires and I made a125V 2-pole flat plug to test the pull chain and sockets connection

Comment: It would help to know more about how you tested it.  There are several methods. There is an "edit" button right below your post that lets you change it.

Comment: Have you unscrewed the bulb and tested the socket--voltage from the center contact to the side contact?

Comment: Also, just to make sure, test the bulb in another known working socket to rule out a burnt out bulb.